# Switch to editor pane shortcut not working in Spyder 5.X

Tags: python, windows, ide, keyboard-shortcuts, spyder

I'm on Windows 10 and recently updated to Spyder 5.3.3 standalone version and the keyboard shortcut to switch to the editor pane (default Ctrl+E) will not work no matter what I try, it simply has no effect.

I've tried reinstalling Spyder, resetting everything back to defaults multiple times, changing to different keyboard shortcuts than Ctrl+E, trying to switch to the editor pane while having various other panes selected (different contexts), but nothing helps. I can switch to all other panes (like the console with Ctrl+I, etc) just fine and so far all of the other key shortcuts I'm used to work but this one is the most impactful and I can't get it to work. I opened my previous version of Spyder 4.X and the Ctrl+E works fine from any context as expected.

Any ideas on what the issue could be?

Answer (score 2):

Same issue here, and I think the issue started with the upgrade from 5.3.2 to 5.3.3 only. Before that it still worked.

Comment: Thanks @Lendicap, I'll try the earlier versions to see if that fixes it and if it does that's likely just a bug so I'll report it on the spyder github page.

Comment: also have the same problem with 5.3.3.

Comment: Quick update that I tried downgrading to 5.2.2 without changing anything else and it works fine then so it does appear to be version specific. I submitted this github issue so hopefully it'll be fixed soon:

https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/19928

Comment: I figured out how to install 5.3.2 via conda-forge and it appears that the shortcut still works in that version so it seems it is indeed very specific to 5.3.3 as Lendicap suggests.

Answer (score 1):

The issue appears to be version-specific.

Have upgraded from 5.3.3 to 5.4.0, and the shortcut is working again.

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) This bug was introduced in our 5.3.3 version but fixed in 5.4.0.

Comment: @CarlosCordoba - Thank you for your hard work on Spyder! Very much appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for your kind words! We try to address this kind of regressions quickly because we know they're very annoying for our users.